# how to change a particular index of gps latitude and longitude

Tags: java, android, indexing, latitude-longitude

i want to add the index of Real-time updating GPS latitude and longitude for e.g. if i am having lat,lng `(18.6032,73.7910)` then i want to add the `8th` and `9th` index with the value from `00` to `99`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

here there are a solution. this is mts

Original post: https://dzone.com/articles/distance-calculation-using-3

```
private void distance(double lat1, double lon1,double lat2, double lon2) {
    double theta = lon1 - lon2;
    double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = rad2deg(dist);
    this.distancia = dist * 60 * 1.1515 * 1609.344;
}


/**
 * This function converts decimal degrees to radians
 * @param deg
 * @return
 */
private static double deg2rad(double deg) {
  return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

/**
 * This function converts radians to decimal degrees 
 * @param rad
 * @return
 */
private static double rad2deg(double rad) {
  return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```